# Sitecore subnav issue

Tags: drop-down-menu, sitecore

I have updated the subnav menu for a title in the "Producto" main nav dropdown. It appears correctly on all tabs except when the home tab (Compania) is active; then if you view the dropdown of "producto" you will see "Bocadillos y Pequenas comidas" when it should say "bocadillos y mini-comidas". If you click on any other tab in the main nav and then view the dropdown of "producto" you will see the proper title "bocadillos y mini-comidas." Does anyone know why the home tab would be the only one showing the wrong title? I have publish and republish over the past several days and there has been no change.

The url is http://isagenix.com/es-MX/network-marketing-company

Comment: Are you sure the field that is used to render this data has a hyphen?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it may have been a cache issue because it is now showing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a caching issue. All nave items updated except for the home tab for some reason and after a while it appeared correctly on all pages.